# Advanced Display Settings is missing on Dell Dell Latitude 5591 laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-10, dell-latitude, laptop-display

I have a Dell Latitude 5591 laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise:

[image]

https://youtu.be/LpQnhFvJ6no?t=63 and many other sites state that there is an Advanced Display Settings button/link on the Display Settings window, but on my revision of Windows 10 it is not there. This is what I see instead:

[image]

Is it the Display Adapter Properties now and Microsoft retitled it?

What I'm looking for is what the laptop thinks the display refresh rate is, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using an OS two years out of date? That said, it might be hidden by Group Policy settings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It is a company-issued laptop. They keep it updated per their policy's which I don't/can't question. I looked through "Group Policy settings" via gpedit.msc (https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-access-local-group-policy-editor-on-windows-10.html) and didn't see anything other than "Not configured".

Answer (score 0):

The Display adapter properties in the link in the OP is where the Refresh Rate is shown.  It is in the second tab.  Windows changed it for some reason, so the old web pages are out of date:

[image]